# Custom Font Preview

Tags: javascript, php, fonts

I am a `font designer` and want to create a similar custom `font previewer` like on `dafont.com` and `myfonts.com`

Those websites allow users to test a font with custom preview text. Also, I notice the preview text is generated as an image.

I have been working with a `ifr.js` tutorial on [this website](http://www.marcofolio.net/webdesign/use_a_custom_font_on_your_website.html)

However, I can't get it to work properly with custom text. The text changes, but it no longer displays as an image but as regular text.

I am very new at coding, so please dumb it down for me :)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeText2(){
var userInput = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
    document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = userInput;
    
if(userInput == ""){
    document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = "Testing...";
}
}
</script>

<script type="text/JavaScript" src="ifr.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="userInput" placeholder="Enter Text Here" />
<input type="button" onclick="changeText2()" value="submit"/>

<p class="title" id="title">Testing...</p>
```

Also, are websites like `dafont` or `myfonts` using something like I am trying to use or do they use something very custom?

Thanks in advance!....

Comment: This is not a good question to ask on Stackoverflow - what you want is a fair bit of work, and if you're new to programming, not something that can be answered in a concise post, except by omitting all the information you actually *need*. To do this "properly", you'd need to have a server running that can use your font with a real font engine, as CSS and the Canvas2D APIs don't have full OpenType support even today, so not all opentype features your fonts use can be shown except by generating an image outside of the browser.

Comment: That said, there are JS libraries that can do limited types of font shaping purely in JS, such as http://opentype.js.org, so my advice is to read through its examples, and see how far you can get with that. But these won't let do you the complex opentype feature selection that actually makes a font preview useful. If you just want to "see what it looks like in the plain form", then a CSS `@font-face` rule is more than enough and you don't even need to generate any images, unless you want to spare your users the memory burden of loading fonts.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer! It is a bit of an overwhelming task, especially since I don't know my way around yet :D I will check out the opentype.js. It looks close enough to what I want.

Comment: fwiw if I went to a font designer's site and wanted to check out their font, having some sample text would be fine (as opposed to text I could change). That said, I would probably never find that designer's site - I'd just go to one of the big font sites. Maybe look into submitting your font to fontsquirrel (if it's free), myfonts, etc?

Comment: I built one but it requires a fair amount of manual work each time a new font is released ... essentially the font files are uploaded to the website, styling is put in place in a css file, & the js is defined accordingly on each listing. I'm interested in streamlining the process myself, have a look here: https://beckmccormick.com/product/the-brush-font-bundle/